# Anomalous orbit of pluto

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

Can anyone explain,  why, like unlike all planets, Pluto does not have a regular orbit?

Why does it have an orbit that meets the orbit of Neptune?

Why does it never collides with Neptune?

Is it a mere coincidence?

Comment: Already answered in http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/753/

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128521/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Note that the definition of *planet* has changed & Pluto no longer is considered one, cf [this Physics post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141504/) for some of the details.